# how to use move_uploaded_file to save file from getfile in telegram

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

How to use `move_uploaded_file` to save file from Get File in **telegram**.

My code is :

[image]

```
move_uploaded_file("https://api.telegram.org/file/
            botMYTOKEN/photo/file_4.jpg", "/images/1.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a http path with move_uploaded file. It have to be a filesystem path.